# paint a grid of icons

Tags: java, canvas, for-loop, grid

I'm trying to paint a grid of icons from an `ArrayList` onto my `canvas` where every after every 10 icons, the next icon will display on a new row, but cant seem to get it to work right. The beginning X and Y position of the first icon is at 100, 100:

```
int x = 32; // Dimensions of icons
int y = x;

for (int pos = 0; pos < icons.getIcon().size(); pos++)
    {
        if(pos % 10 == 0)
        {

            icons.getIcon().get(pos).paintIcon(canvas, graphics, posX, posY);
        }
        else
        {
            icons.getIcon().get(pos).paintIcon(canvas, graphics, posX, posY);
            posX += x + 10;
        }
    }
```

This will display the each icon in a horizontal row, but can't figure out how to get the 11th and every 10th after to start on a new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to add the "line break", when it detects it's the 11th icon. Something like that:

```
int x = 32; // Dimensions of icons
int y = x;
int posX = 100;
int posY = 100;

for (int pos = 0; pos < icons.getIcon().size(); pos++) {
    if(pos % 10 == 0) {
        posY += y + 10;
        posX = 100; // Returns posX back to the left-most position
        icons.getIcon().get(pos).paintIcon(canvas, graphics, posX, posY);
    } else {
        icons.getIcon().get(pos).paintIcon(canvas, graphics, posX, posY);
    }
    posX += x + 10; // Do that out of the if, so that posX is incremented either way
}
```